# Приведение нижней треугольной матрицы к симметричной

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, numpy, матрицы

Есть нижняя треугольная матрица вида:

```
0.0
0.5 0.0
0.4 0.6 0.0
```

записана как список списков *[[0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.4, 0.6, 0.0]]*

Как сделать матрицу полной? Привести к виду:

```
0.0 0.5 0.4
0.5 0.0 0.6
0.4 0.6 0.0
```

Догадываюсь что есть какой-то метод в **numpy**, но с этим пакетом я слабо знаком, не могу найти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать и `numpy`, но я не уверен, что там есть векторизированный подход к заполнению матрицы. Поэтому советую использовать `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

a =  [[0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.4, 0.6, 0.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df=df.combine_first(df.T)
print(df)
```

Получаем:

```
     0    1    2
0  0.0  0.5  0.4
1  0.5  0.0  0.6
2  0.4  0.6  0.0
```

Если нужно получить не датафрейм, а список списков, то можно добавтить:

```
res = df.values.tolist()
print(res)
```

Что даст:

```
[[0.0, 0.5, 0.4], [0.5, 0.0, 0.6], [0.4, 0.6, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если она не огромного размера, достаточно так

```
a
[[0.0], [0.5, 0.0], [0.4, 0.6, 0.0]]

b = [[a[i][j] if j<= i else a[j][i] for j in range(len(a))] for i in range(len(a))]

b
[[0.0, 0.5, 0.4], [0.5, 0.0, 0.6], [0.4, 0.6, 0.0]]
```